# Is it possible to connect with an Oracle Docker container with an ODBC?

Tags: database, oracle, docker, odbc, unixodbc

I am using docker images from this github: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images

I installed oracle db version 19c in my environment with the following command:

```
docker  run --name oracle19c --network host -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500
 -v /opt/oracle:/u01/oracle oracle/database:19.3.0-ee
```

Then I connect to it to run sqlplus with:

```
docker exec -ti oracle19c sqlplus system/oracle@orclpdb1
SQL>
```

Then I managed to successfully load some data into it. However, I would like to connect to the database with an ODBC connection. However, I am confused on going about and connecting to the database inside docker, I have not been able to find any resources or guides. The server runs Ubuntu and I am connected over an ssh connection if that helps.

Edit:I tried with unixodbc but I would be willing to switch over to any other available options.

Comment: Since you're disabling Docker networking with `--network host`, you'll have trouble connecting to this container from other containers (you should also get a warning that `-p` is ignored).  That option shouldn't usually be necessary; does removing it and using normal inter-container communication help?  What have you already tried and what problems are you running into?

Comment: I don't know where to get started. I'm new to docker environment and have unixodbc driver and driver manager downloaded and installed, but do not know how to connect it all to docker, for instance what do i put in odbcinst.ini?